# sparse-QR more rows than original matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I did a sparse `qr` decomposition with `"Matrix"` package in `R` like

```
a <- Matrix(runif(20), nrow = 5, sparse = T)
a[3:5,] <- 0 #now **a** is a 5X4 matrix
b <- qr.R(qr(a), complete = T) #but now **b** is a 7X4 matrix!
```

anyone knows why? Note that if I keep `a` dense, then the bug(?) does not appear.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you did not see the warning, otherwise you would have mentioned it, right?

> Warning message:
>   In qr.R(qr(a), complete = T) :
>     qr.R(< sparse >) may differ from qr.R(< dense >) because of permutations

Now if you are asking what those permutations mean, it's a different story...

The `help("sparseQR-class")` page may have more info on the issue:

> However, because the matrix Q is not uniquely defined, the results of qr.qy and qr.qty do not necessarily match those from the corresponding dense matrix calculations.

Maybe it is the same with `qr.R`?

Finally, further down on the same help page:

> *qr.R* --- signature(qr = "sparseQR"): compute the upper triangular R matrix of the QR decomposition. Note that this currently warns because of possible permutation mismatch with the classical qr.R() result, and you can suppress these warnings by setting options() either "Matrix.quiet.qr.R" or (the more general) either "Matrix.quiet" to TRUE.

Comment: well I have nearly read the whole manual of "Matrix" package... I checked the Household transform information claimed to be stored in qr(a)@V but found that the length of the columns of V is usually different from that of a, yet the row length of V equals always to that of a (it seems that V stores the information to make a column operation instead of a row operation)

Comment: It seems that the "qr" methods tends to put some zero rows beneath the sparse matrix a when computing qr(a), this leads to a large orthogonal matrix Q (obtained via a long march of joining Householder transforms stored in qr(a)@V and qr(a)@beta). Suppose a is of size mXn, then mysteriously Q[1:m, ] %*% qr(a)@R[ ,order(qr(a)@q)] recovers a (please be tolerant about the computing complexity issues for these demonstrating examples). I got *so* confused why these zero rows are added.

Comment: I also don't understand why the zero rows are added. When you do a[3:4,]<-0 you get an R matrix of dimension 6x4. Looks a bit weird. Maybe you should mail the Matrix authors at <Matrix-authors@R-project.org> and show them your example. I tried your gx.qr.Q function (from  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10038276/how-do-i-do-a-qr-decomposition-on-an-object-of-class-sparsematrix-in-the-matri?rq=1) and that seems to give correct results.

Comment: good suggestions. I have sent the email. Let's wait for the author group's reply. In case they visit here, I put my R version: R version 2.14.1 (2011-12-22), Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit), Matrix version: Version: 1.0-2 Date: 2011-11-02 Packaged: 2011-11-19 22:59:10 UTC; maechler
Repository: CRAN
Date/Publication: 2011-11-20 18:43:23
Built: R 2.14.0; x86_64-pc-linux-gnu; 2011-12-05 14:17:01 UTC; unix

Comment: Just in case it is needed. I am running R 2.15.1 patched (r59954) on Mac OS X 10.6.8. And using Matrix Version 1.0-6

Comment: It would be helpful if you could extend your gx.qr.? functions to also have a `complete` argument.